# Multiple Tab IF Statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, tabs

I'm having a hard time figuring out if this is an IF statement or if this would be a Macro.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have multiple tabs with the same rows A-E.  The rows are as follows: Date, Broker/Prospect, Property, Action, Status.

I have a master tracking sheet where all of the data will be entered.  The 'Property' row refers to the address of the property and the different tabs are the different property address.

I want to have the input on the master sheet automatically fill in the same information on the correlating tabs, depending on the address that is entered in the 'property' row on the master sheet.

IF(Master_Tracking (sheet1), Row C = property address, then the data in the entire column on the master sheet will automatically fill in the entire column on the seperate tabs, which correlate to their particular address.

Hope this makes sense.  It's been a long time since I've use VBA and forget how to code.

Comment: This would probably best be done in a Worksheet_Change event.  Any Formula answer would need to have full sheets of formula that are filled with Array formulas.  That would slow down the calculation to a crawl.

Comment: just a side note, you seem to be transposing rows and columns. columns are lettered `A-Z ... XFD` and go across the sheet from left-to-right. Rows are numerical and go from top-to-bottom.

Comment: yes, I was transposing! haha, thanks.  Thank you Scott Craner, I'll check that out.